# Typescript: Infer type for parameter of passed function

Tags: typescript, generics

I need to be able to infer the argument type of a function that is passed as a parameter, based on another parameter where the type is known. It's kinda hard to explain so I wrote a [little demo](https://agentcooper.github.io/typescript-play/?target=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKojlAngMQK4gJjAD2IAPAJIgA0yA8nmAHzIDeAUMt8gBSYBzAFzJqAShGMwHAL4cOoSLEQoA6sDAALAHJ4AtgCNoVWgyasIAD0ggAJgGc0GbPkLEyJulNaceyEPoiAYbQsvIwBESkIMiQ9mAAotYQdvbkAIJQAnQ4MVY2Dk6YuJHuFJnZyHAgWMzM-FkiFXQwICK5YuxcPFAQYHhQMa1hHBFu0bEQ8dQw0L22GVn1gk1ZLW1FLqXRi5XVtZ2+PX0DQyAjY1FkyHpwAA7qWgDCcAA2r8Y4UCR6dAAqJHqehIUDummA9j0InQxVcVwoXx+-0BEmQjx0+iMUHIiN+yABPm63F6-UGDAMACsIEQAHRwez2YACEC8XiWdrfPSdAC8rGBoPBkLZYjobGCIgArDIxCM4olkqleAByACMSrotweGk0L3e0DZyF5yEsNI+IAEWjEYhpwQ4cpmcwgtmVao193Ruo+UANRpNZotmitNv0QA), reproduced here:

```
interface UnaryFunction<In, Out> {
    (arg: In): Out
}

interface WithNumber<In, Out> extends UnaryFunction<In, Out> {
    num: number
}

function testExtends<Arg, Fn extends UnaryFunction<Arg, any>>(arg: Arg, fn: Fn): Fn {
    return fn;
}

function testInferred<Arg, Out>(arg: Arg, fn: UnaryFunction<Arg, Out>): typeof fn {
    return fn
}

function mapWithCaller<From, To>(morphism: UnaryFunction<From, To>): WithNumber<From, To> {
    return Object.assign((x: From) => morphism(x), {num: 5})
}

// Error: property length does not exist
testExtends('1', mapWithCaller(x => x.length)).num
// Error: property num does not exist
testInferred('1', mapWithCaller(x => x.length)).num
```

As you can see, with `testExtends` the return type of the function is preserved, while with `testInferred` the parameter type of the passed function is inferred.

I need to be able to combine the best of both worlds, and it's driving me crazy, is this not possible at all? Is it a bug? By design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `testInferred`'s return type is fairly obvious - it's non-generic and the return type is fixed at exactly `UnaryFunction`

The problem with `testExtends` is more complex. The root cause here is that you need the argument to `mapWithCaller` to be *contextually typed* by a function type that is capable of providing a contextual type to the argument.

You actually have a somewhat indirect contextual type coming in here because `mapWithCaller` is itself generic, but because the other argument to `testInferred` is provided and TypeScript can route the expected return type of `mapWithCaller` back into its arguments, it's not a problem.

Anyway, `testInferred` works here because `UnaryFunction<In, Out>` is a non-generic function type with a single call signature.

Why doesn't `testExtends` work for this? Because it's not safe to apply a contextual type to a parameter based on the bound in the `extends` clause. Consider this call, which is legal (apart from the error in the lambda expression):

```
interface OtherFunction<Out> {
    (arg: string | number): Out
}

testExtends<string, OtherFunction<number>>('1', mapWithCaller(x => x.length));
```

Based on a *legal generic instantiation here*, `mapWithCaller` *is allowed* to pass a `number` to its callback. TypeScript can't really assume that given a string argument in one position, the correct inferred bound for the function expression is exactly that.

I don't think there's a way to write the function declaration here in a way that preserves both behaviors you want, but I could be wrong.

Comment: that is a VERY nice explanation, thank you for your time and effort. Do you think it's a good idea to create a new issue on github/microsoft/typescript? Sadly I'm not fit enough with the terminology of this to express my intent accurately, would you be willing to help me here?

Comment: There's not a bug here, so no.